# React login using context API with private route

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks

In my react web app, login-logout functionality is implemented using context-API and hooks. Everything seems to work fine except for the fact that I have to click the 'Login' button twice to push the user to the dashboard.

The statement, `return <Redirect to="/dashboard />` does not work, instead I have to use `history.push('/dashboard')`, which does not seems to be a better option to me while login.

Here is the working snippet :
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-worker-mqkex?file=/src/AuthContext.js

Also, I need some suggestions for the best practise to fetch the logged user details in other components. Using localstorage or global context API state, which of them serves as the best option for the same ?

Any help to resolve this, appreciated :)

Comment: Well, when you use `localStorage` you can persist the data when reloads occur which is not possible when using the context Api.

Comment: @Gh05d Okay. And any help regarding my login issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it boils down to the simple fact that your context is not updated when you do your check. The simplest solution would be to remove the check for `isLoggedIn` and push the user to the Dashboard:

```
  const postLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      await login()

      props.history.push('/dashboard')
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE',
        payload: 'Unable to login'
      })
    }
  }
```

Then throw an error in your `login` function when you don't get a *200* back:

```
const login = async () => {
    const loginUser = { status: 200, id: '3654634565659abhdgh' }

    if (loginUser.status === 200) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
        payload: loginUser.id
      })
    } else {
      throw new Error("Invalid Credentials")
    }
  }
```

As your login code is in a `try catch` block, the user won't get pushed to the Dashboard when the login fails.